# Taking Common elements of three sets

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have three numpy arrays.

```
[40  9  0 12 49  1  3  4 18 13 34 47]

[40  0 28 39 29 27 50  9 42 41]

[40  0  9 48 46  1 38 45 15 27 31 36  3 12 16 41 30 33 22 37 28  4  2  6 50
 29 32 49 35  7 11 23 44 42 14 13]
```

Now I want to get all the elements which are common to either two or all sets. Like in above, first three are common to all three elements so those would be retained. Then you see, 12 is common to 1 and third set, so even that should be retained even if it is not there in 2 set. 50 is common to 2 set and third so even that should be retained even if it is not there in first set.

So basically either any pair wise common or all common should be retained.

I did something like this but as it is clear this would keep all distinct from the three sets.

```
set(list(shortlistvar_rf)) & set(list(shortlistvar_f)) & set(list(shortlistvar_rl))
```

Comment: Can there be duplicates within any of those input arrays?

Answer (score 4):

Numpy has a number of [set operations](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.set.html) for 1D arrays that you could use. Before writing any code, note that the general formula for what you are after:

```
(a & b) | (b & c) | (c & a)
```

Can be reduced using [boolean algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_%28set_theory%29#Union_and_intersection) to:

```
(b & (a | c)) | (a & c)
```

which requires 4 instead of 5 operations.

With this in mind, you can simply do:

```
>>> np.union1d(np.intersect1d(b, np.union1d(a, c)), np.intersect1d(a, c))
array([ 0,  1,  3,  4,  9, 12, 13, 27, 28, 29, 40, 41, 42, 49, 50])
```

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> a = [40,  9,  0, 12 ,49  ,1  ,3  ,4 ,18 ,13 ,34 ,47]
>>> b = [40  ,0 ,28 ,39 ,29 ,27 ,50  ,9 ,42 ,41]
>>> c = [40  ,0  ,9 ,48 ,46  ,1 ,38 ,45 ,15 ,27 ,31 ,36  ,3 ,12 ,16 ,41 ,30 ,33 ,22 ,37 ,28  ,4  ,2  ,6 ,50,29 ,32 ,49 ,35  ,7 ,11 ,23 ,44 ,42 ,14 ,13]
>>> (set(a) & set(b)) | (set(a) & set(c)) | (set(b) & set(c))
{0, 1, 3, 4, 40, 9, 42, 41, 12, 13, 49, 50, 27, 28, 29}
```

Comment: These are numpy arrays. So I should be converting them to list first. Is that right as set operations don't work on numpy arrays

Comment: If you can convert them to `list`s with `list()`, then you can probably convert them to `set`s with `set()` without having to turn them into `list`s first. I only used `list`s here because my machine doesn't have numpy installed.

Comment: when I do set(numpy.array) it gives error saying set operations not defined.

Comment: Try something like `set(x for x in a)` or `set(iter(a))`, which gives `set()` a generator expression. I assume numpy arrays behave as iterables, right?

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate unique elements versions of those three input arrays into one single array. Then, sort and find out the runlengths of identical elements. The elements corresponding to runlengths greater than `1` would be the elements that are at least in two of those original input arrays.

Here's the implementation -

```
import numpy as np

# Get unique elements versions of input arrays
unqA = np.unique(A)
unqB = np.unique(B)
unqC = np.unique(C)

# Combine them into one single array and then sort it
comb_sorted = np.sort(np.hstack((unqA,unqB,unqC)))

# Find indices where group changes, where a group means a run of idential elements.
# These identical elements basically represent those common elements between inputs.
idx  = np.where(np.diff(comb_sorted))[0]
grp_change = np.hstack([ [-1],idx,[comb_sorted.size-1] ])+1

# Finally, get the runlengths of each group, detect those runlength > 1 and,
# get the corresponding elements from the combined array
common_ele = comb_sorted[grp_change[np.diff(grp_change)>1]]
```

### Benchmarking

Listed in this section are some runtimes tests comparing the proposed approach against the other approach for numpy arrays using `union` and `intersect` in [`@Jaime's solution`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29958834/3293881).

**Case #1:** For inputs arrays that already have uniqiue elements in them -

Setup input arrays:

```
A = np.random.randint(0,1000,[1,1000000])
B = np.random.randint(0,1000,[1,1000000])
C = np.random.randint(0,1000,[1,1000000])

A = A.ravel()
B = B.ravel()
C = C.ravel()

_, idx1 = np.unique(A, return_index=True)
A = A[np.sort(idx1)]

_, idx2 = np.unique(B, return_index=True)
B = B[np.sort(idx2)]

_, idx3 = np.unique(C, return_index=True)
C = C[np.sort(idx3)]
```

Runtimes:

```
In [6]: %timeit concat(A,B,C)
10000 loops, best of 3: 136 µs per loop

In [7]: %timeit union_intersect(A,B,C)
1000 loops, best of 3: 315 µs per loop
```

---

**Case #2:** For generic input arrays that could have duplicates -

Setup input arrays:

```
A = np.random.randint(0,1000,[1,1000000])
B = np.random.randint(0,1000,[1,1000000])
C = np.random.randint(0,1000,[1,1000000])

A = A.ravel()
B = B.ravel()
C = C.ravel()
```

Runtimes:

```
In [24]: %timeit concat(A,B,C)
10 loops, best of 3: 102 ms per loop

In [25]: %timeit union_intersect(A,B,C)
10 loops, best of 3: 172 ms per loop
```

Comment: Nice! You are doing [what `np.intersect1d` does](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.9.1/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py#L214), generalized to more than 2 arrays, by far a better solution than mine. If you can redo it to use boolean instead of integer indexing, i.e. get rid of the `where` call, see the linked code for an example, you should give performance a big boost.

Comment: @Jaime I did try using `boolean indexing`, but then since I need to find runlengths, I figured I would need to find those shifting indices and then perform `diff`, so `np.where` might be the preferred way here. It's good to see those solutions, seems like inherently I am just ending up with solutions that are based off the source codes of all these numpy builtin functions! :) Appreciate you sharing these links!

Comment: Can't test it right now, but doesn't `idx = np.concatenate(([True], comb_sorted[:-1] != comb_sorted[1:])); common_ele = comb_sorted[idx]` work?